# PHP script inside Django template

Tags: php, django, templates, application-server

Hp: having the possibility of running an application server with both a Py interpreter with Django and a PHP engine...

It would be possible to run a PHP script into a Django template?

Is it possible to implement such application server through Apache 2.0 mods?

How would the `views` and the template file look like?

Comment: ... why would you do this? Eek.

Comment: I am traslating a beta project from PHP to Python. I would need a double implementation to switch the db talbes' model from the old one to the new one.

Comment: You don't need any such implementation. Just write your Django models to interface with the tables as they exist now.

Comment: old tables are really a mess. wrong types, utf-8 collation. So I think I will make custom script to migrate these tables to solid 'Django compliant' tables. I have already created the model, but the old data doesn't fit into new tables. So I though to use the data I cannot migrate into separate php pages, inside the django template. That's what I was asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is awful idea, but you can check [this project](http://animuchan.net/django_php/).

Comment: :D the project looks like a weird interbreeding