# Django and PHP simultaneous use

Tags: php, python, django, apache

I have an `Apache` server with `PHP` support. I also installed `Python` with `mod_wsgi` and with `mysql-connector`. Besides I installed Django. Now, I want to try to use `PHP` and `Python` simultaneously at the server side. The catch is, I worked with `PHP` for a couple of years and I see that it is becoming less and less popular, so I plan to port some of my PHP-code to Python-code, or just to try it, to see how they work together. So, I now have a site located at `C:\Apache\htdocs` and I created a first `Django` project at `C:\WebPython\djsite`. Inside `djsite` I have `djsite` folder and four files `_init_.py, settings.py, urls.py and wsgi.py`. In my site I want to address both to PHP handlers (or scripts) and to Python scripts, so, I guess, the problem is in how to config `httpd.conf`. I looked through many forum threads here at stackoverflow and outside, but still I can't make it work. Now, my httpd.conf looks like this:

```
...
ServerName localhost
<Directory "c:/Apache/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory> 
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</IfModule>
...
```

Comment: Do you want them to run simultaneously on the same application?

Comment: Yes, I want them to run simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see this question then:

[PHP script inside Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891653/php-script-inside-django-template)

It has a link to this:

http://animuchan.net/django_php/

Running PHP with Django would be a mess though.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Like Every Body Else Said Its A terrible idea but Refer To Django Documentation adding this to http.conf on your apache2  and tweek 
   the  wsgi.py file will work
     WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
     WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com`<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>`

and change 
If multiple Django sites are run in a single mod_wsgi process, all of them will use the settings of whichever one happens to run first. This can be solved by changing:

in wsgi.py, to:

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "{{ project_name }}.settings"
```

or by using mod_wsgi daemon mode and ensuring that each site runs in its own daemon process.

Fixing UnicodeEncodeError for file uploads

If you get a UnicodeEncodeError when uploading files with file names that contain non-ASCII characters, make sure Apache is configured to accept non-ASCII file names:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

A common location to put this configuration is /etc/apache2/envvars.

See the Files section of the Unicode reference guide for details.

See More At https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/